# dataset .net cannot resolve on java web service client

Tags: java, .net, eclipse, netbeans, dataset

I have a web service built in .NET with a dataset as input parameter and another dataset as a response. I need to consume it from java but this does not work.

Eclipse show:

```
   Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
DsClient cannot be resolved to a type   ServiceSoap12Stub.java  /xxxx/src/org/tempuri   line 169    Java Problem
```

Netbeans show:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight and easy answer is that DataSet should **never** be used for data exchange in open services. So the provider of this *non* service should provide an API which could be used.

The fact that one can export a service with a click (or wizard, or tool ... ) does not mean that he should not plan carefully how that service will be consumed.

Even succeeding in operating such a service is a *workaround* in my opinion.

That being said, it seems that you are not using the full definition of the service. WSDL could be provided as single file or split in many, often keeping schema information in a separate file.

You should be certain to be able to process all files related to the service.

Analyze the WSDL, there should schemas reference on it, check if those .xsd are available and see if they to refer to other non standard schema.

If you are still stuck, publish the whole WSDL (maybe on some GIST or pastebin) so that we can check and see if something is amiss.

As I said before, the only true solution to this problem lies with the provider of the service, he should really provide a more interoperable API.

Comment: Thank for your answer, Maybe the best way to solve this is changing dataset to a class ?

Comment: Absolutely, you should use plain objects as data, only fields with possibly just getters and setters.